# Capturing the HOME key with getchar()

Tags: linux, terminal, keyboard, getchar

I am writing a command line interface for a console program on Linux. I want to be able to use keys like arrows in it. So to capture the codes, I am using this simple program:

```c
int main()
{
    int c = 0;
    while (c != 3) { // ctrl-c
        c = getchar();
        printf("%d\n", c);
    }
}
```

Doing this I had problems capturing the HOME key. On one computer I got the sequence "27 91 72", on another I got "27 79 72" and on a third I got "27 91 49 126".

I am not sure why I am getting so different codes on HOME and END keys (Arrows and F1-F12 keys gave the same sequence on the three computers).

Is there a standard way to get this keys, or some sort of configuration that would give me the same sequence on all machines?

Comment: The escape codes sent by "special" keys differ by terminal type, and, what's worse, they do not necessarily form a prefix code. You should use [curses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29) to manage all this for you.

Comment: By the way, normally `c` will never equal to `3` because if the uses presses Ctrl-C then you will get a `SIGINT` signal instead.

Comment: This is a more complex question than you're imagining ... the code generated depends on the terminal type (and the text console, xterm, gnome or kde terminals or the windows command line are all different in that aspect) as well as on console driver or X keymap settings. The Linux Text Terminal HOWTO, http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Text-Terminal-HOWTO.html gives some starting points, particularly see section 6 (definitely use and follow the links provided there). If you want to do this in a _portable_ way (without lots of term-type-dependent code), use a library like `ncurses`.

Comment: You probably want to use [terminfo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminfo) for this, if not curses

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use the curses framework.

When using curses it is quiet easy to get special key presses. But the downside is you have to pull in the whole curses library at link time (e.g. with gcc -lcurses) and you have to use all the curses function inside an initialized curses screen.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curses.h>

int main()
{
    int c = 0;
    initscr();
    keypad(stdscr, 1);
    c = getch();
    endwin();
    printf("0x%04x\n", c);
    printf("0x%04x\n", KEY_HOME);
}
```

This will initialize the standard screen (stdscr), enable the keypad in it and get a key-press using getch() and close the stdscr again retoring the tty modes.

You can also check if a special key is supported in your current terminal using the has_key() function.

That is the easy way..

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but unfortunately I need this for a embedded device, and the curses library are not available.

Comment: @Akobold: `curses` is free software, as is the `terminfo` DB used by it. Which one you use doesn't matter anywhere near as much as _not reinventing the wheel_ ...

Comment: I'm implying that compiling `ncurses` for your embedded environment, even, if necessary, first porting it, will save you time.

Comment: As long as you can control the environment your application runs in you can also just hardcode the sequence you get on your embedded device - which might be stable over time for this embedded device? So you do not need to reinvent the wheel (as frank said) and do not need to compare with real terminal settings at all?